# Which position in Russia is more powerful in the field of economy?

Tags: economy, russian-federation

Which position in Russia is more powerful in the field of the economy:

- [Chairman of the Accounts Chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Kudrin#Chairman_of_the_Accounts_Chamber)
- [Minister of Finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Siluanov)

and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chairman of the Accounts Chamber is more powerful, but it is some another power.

Chairman is, in fact, an auditor of goverment's spendings. So, he doesn't decide how to spend budget. But he looks over ways how goverment do it and reports directly to president.

Comment: [this article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-05-14/russia-s-kudrin-gets-audit-post-as-hopes-of-bigger-role-fade), which I found later, disagrees with your answer.

Comment: In which way? It is a watch dog for goverment's spendings. Do you mean your another question, about why it is Kudrin?

Comment: According to the article, `Earlier this month, Kudrin was said to be consideration for a top job in economic policy in the Kremlin where he would have helped direct overhauls to accelerate growth. ` - Kudrin was probably opting for Minister of Finance position. But, he got the position of Chairman of the Accounts Chamber. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And in my answer for your another question I explained why, in my opinion, it is so.
But I don't think that this position is less powerfull. It is just another.

Comment: `Yes, you are correct.` - So, you need to clarify that in your answer.

Comment: Appretiate your removing of claimings about "you are paid".But really, your question is WHY. How answer can be YES?